# HP Envy 23 - Dim/Turn Off Backlight

Tags: windows-8, brightness

In order to listen to music at night I want to turn down/off the background light on my HP Envy 23 without powering off, so the music can play.

How do I turn it off? My search/brightness implies that Windows can't do it on my setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly disable the monitor backlight.

But you can have the screen saver come on to a black screen or "turn off the monitor", via the screen saver features in Windows.

Look at the "power" settings in Windows for turning off the monitor after a while of non-usage.